# Standard SMS image in Android 1.6+

Tags: android

I'm trying to find the standard Android image used in Android 1.6 for an SMS action.  The one that can be seen under contact details that looks like a postcard.

I noticed that there was a standard image "sys_action_sms" which looked like a chat bubble in Android 1.0, but apparently that was removed at some point.

Answer (score 0):

This icon is now part of [Contacts drawables](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=tree;f=res), as well as a new drawable called "badge_action_sms".

I think that you cannot use a drawable from another package, but maybe you can copy it to your project.